# NAs seem to be passed as numeric/double

Tags: r, list, class, dataframe, na

I have a list of data.frames, where every data.frame is populated by different columns of different lengths. At this point, *some* data.frames have elements, the others do not. The first data.frame of this list is currently *not* populated, yet (maybe I'm missing something here) R seems to think that the NAs (I don't know where they came from, since the structure suggests there are no elements there). In the following, 'histdatar' is the name of the list

```
 > dput(histdatar[[1]])
 structure(list(id = numeric(0), likes = numeric(0)), .Names = c("ids", 
 "picks"), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")
 > histdatar[[1]][1,1]
 [1] NA
 > class(histdatar[[1]][1,1])
 [1] "numeric"
 > typeof(histdatar[[1]][1,1])
 [1] "double"
 > length(histdatar[[1]][1,1])
 [1] 1
```

The structure of the data.frame in the first position of the list is the following:

```
 > str(histdatar[[1]])
 'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ids   : num 
 $ picks: num
```

My question is how to deal with these NAs? I am writing a function that requires every column to be populated by elements of numeric/integer classes and, when a data.frame is populated by actual numbers, they work. In this case, the check fails and the function (used via a lapply) stops at the first column where there are these Nas.

Comment: Your data.frame has zero rows in it. Thus you are indexing outside of the bounds of the column vector, and in R, the default behavior when someone tries to index outside the bounds of any vector is to return `NA`. There is no "actual" `NA` stored in the data.frame, it's merely the return value of an out-of-bounds index operation. Same as `numeric()[1]`.

Comment: What would be a correct way to check inside the data.frame whether there are elements in a particular row?

Comment: All columns have the same number of rows in a data.frame; check with `nrow(df)>0`. If you want to check before iterating over the data.frames, use `all(sapply(histdatar,nrow)>0)` or something along those lines.